# How to overload operator<< to show my list

Tags: c++, list

I've been trying to overload the `<<` operator for my list, but I just can't output it. I have the following error and I don't know how to fix it:

> error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << *it (std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* with _Tp = Joc)'

These are the methods that I tried to overload the `<<` operator with, but neither of them worked to output my list using iterators. I don't know how to fix it.

```
ostream& Joc::afisare(ostream &os) const
{        
    os << endl;
    os << "Numele jocului:" << this->nume << ' ' << "Stoc:" << this->stoc << ' ' << "Descrierea joc: " << this->Descriere << ' ';
    for(list<string>::const_iterator it = upd.begin(); it != upd.end(); it++)
    {
        os << "Lista:" << *it << endl;
    }
    os << endl;
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Joc &j)
{
    return j.afisare(os);
}

void Joc::afisare() const
{
    cout << "Numele jocului:" << this->nume << ' ' << "Stoc:" << this->stoc << ' ' << "Descrierea joc: " << this->Descriere << ' ';
    for(list<string>::const_iterator it = upd.begin(); it != upd.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << "Lista:" << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
list<Joc> jx;

jx.push_back(j6);
jx.push_back(j7);

for(list<Joc>::const_iterator it = jx.begin(); it != jx.end(); it++)
{
    cout << *it;
}
```

I tried to use `cout << it->afisare();` but it still didn't work. I don't know what to do.

I think the problem is with the `<<` operator but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The minimum character requirements are in place to guide new user towards writing useful questions. Instead of making your post worse while trying to work around those requirements, you should stop and try to actually fulfill our request to increase your chance of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main loop is using `const_iterator` to iterate the elements of `jx`. When you dereference each iterator, you get a reference to a `const Joc` object.

However, the `j` parameter of your `operator<<` is not declared as `const`, so the compiler cannot find an overload of `operator<<` that accepts a `const Joc` as input, hence the error message.

You need to declare the `j` parameter as `const`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Joc &j)
```

See [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for more details.

That being said, your `afisare()` overloads are duplicating code instead of sharing code. I would suggest an alternative implementation:

```
void Joc::afisare(ostream &os) const
{
    os << "Numele jocului:" << this->nume << ' ' << "Stoc:" << this->stoc << ' ' << "Descrierea joc: " << this->Descriere << ' ';
    for(list<string>::const_iterator it = upd.begin(); it != upd.end(); it++)
    {
        os << "Lista:" << *it << endl;
    }
}

void Joc::afisare() const
{
    afisare(cout);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Joc &j)
{
    os << endl;
    j.afisare(os);
    os << endl; 
    return os;
}
```